# How can I make an OpenLayers map zoom out farther than the div it is in?

Tags: maps, openlayers, openstreetmap

The div that my openlayers map is in is about 300px wide, and I want to zoom down to level 0 (one single 256x256 tile), but I can't in OpenLayers.  But I can with Google maps.

I've looked for a setting, but I can't find it.

All I want to do is see the whole world at the same time. I can in Google maps.  Google lets you see about 150% of the world, but in openlayers in seems to be limited to 100%, which means if I want to see a map of the whole world (a reasonable request) I have to resize my window down to the exact pixel. That's a bit ridiculous.  Is this really so hard to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers 2.12 had a change which prevented the map from zooming out to see two worlds if the base layer is set to wrapDateLine

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/notes/2.12.md#changes-when-base-layer-configured-with-wrapdateline-true

Answer (score 0):

The smallest tile what OpenStreetMap provides is 256x256 (http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png), so you cant get a smaller view of the world without resizing.

Comment: Oh yeah.  Of course you're right.  I just measured, and the div is actually 300px.  I will edit my question.